# Laravel Eloquent: Relationships 2 Layers deep

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 eloquent models set like this:

Forum:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'icon_path',
        'parent_id',
        'display_order',
        'forum_is_open',
    ];

    public function mods()
    {  
        return $this->hasMany(ForumModerator::class);

    }
```

ForumModerator:

```
   protected $fillable = [
        'forum_id',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function forum()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Forum::class, 'forum_id', 'id');

    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');

    }
```

And I'm getting the list of Forums like this:

```
    return Forum::where('forum_is_open', 1)
            ->with(['subForums', 'mods.user'])
            ->orderBy('display_order', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

and this is what the result looks like:

```
{
            "id": 52,
            "title": "Quia eius dolorem est sunt.",
            "description": "Dolore eveniet unde autem debitis. Natus et error quaerat dolor minima.",
            "icon_path": null,
            "parent_id": null,
            "display_order": 1,
            "forum_is_open": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-11-23T22:34:45.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-11-23T22:34:45.000000Z",
            "sub_forums": [],
            "mods": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "forum_id": 52,
                    "user_id": 3,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "username": "Monserrat McCullough",
                        "email": "billy52@example.org",
                        "display_name": "Vincenza Lebsack",
                        "signature": null,
                        "group_id": 1,
                        "post_count": 0,
                        "created_at": "2022-11-25T04:15:12.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2022-11-25T04:15:12.000000Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "forum_id": 52,
                    "user_id": 16,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": 16,
                        "username": "Prof. Norberto Kohler Sr.",
                        "email": "zdach@example.net",
                        "display_name": "Edmund Hickle",
                        "signature": null,
                        "group_id": 1,
                        "post_count": 0,
                        "created_at": "2022-11-25T04:15:12.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2022-11-25T04:15:12.000000Z"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

I'm trying to get the list of mods for each Forum that has a mod, but without the entire ForumModerator record. bascically just want the user object to be in the mods array.

How do I need to set the relation between Forum and ForumModerator models to achive that?

Thanks

looked into `hasManyThrough()` function but wasn't able to achive the desired outcome

Comment: You can create a users relation in the forum model, using hasManyThrough relation, and then simply do ->with('users')

Comment: @Lk77 not sure if I follow. The forum Id and user id are stored in ForumModerator Table. I don't want to save the user id directly in forums table since there might be multiple moderators per forum

Comment: You can create a relation without adding a foreign key to forum table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to probably set up a many-to-many relationship between the `Forum` and the `User` models using the `forum_moderators` table:

```php
class Forum extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'forum_moderators');
    }
}
```

Then you can simply eager load the `users` relationship.

Alternatively, you can always modify your response using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#main-content).

Comment: Thank you so much! this solved it perfectly... also I really like the idea of using resources instead. might have to look into that. Thanks